# How can I add and remove JLabels to a JPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make a little GUI. It has three checkboxes and a button. (picture below) I have an image of a head that I want other images to be put over the top of. This way as I select them and push the button they will change. Currently in my handler I have only one ImageIcon.
When I run the code as it is the "coolBrows.png" image doesn't show up. I've seen some examples on here of adding a JFrame to a JFrame they said that I need to add a layout for it to work. I've done that and it still wont show up... any help is appreciated! 
Note: Each image has the same dimensions but the ones that will be overlayed have a transparent background.

Sorry if I broke with any conventions I've never posted here before.

The GUI

[image]

```
package AssignmentFace;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class AssignmentFace extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private ImageIcon head;
    private JCheckBox checkBoxBrows;
    private static ImageIcon brows; 

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AssignmentFace frame = new AssignmentFace();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public AssignmentFace() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,2));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel selectionPanel = new JPanel();
        selectionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1));
        contentPane.add(selectionPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        // Contains the checkboxes
        checkBoxBrows= new JCheckBox("brows");
        selectionPanel.add(checkBoxBrows);

        JCheckBox checkBoxNose = new JCheckBox("Nose");
        selectionPanel.add(checkBoxNose);

        JCheckBox checkBoxMouth = new JCheckBox("Mouth");
        selectionPanel.add(checkBoxMouth);

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        JButton btnCycle = new JButton("Cycle ...");
        btnCycle.addActionListener(handler);
        selectionPanel.add(btnCycle);

        JPanel facePanel = new JPanel();
        facePanel.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.add(facePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //  Head
        head = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/head.png"));
        JLabel headLabel = new JLabel(head, JLabel.CENTER);
        headLabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        facePanel.add( headLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        //  Brows
        brows = new ImageIcon();
        JLabel browsLabel = new JLabel(brows, JLabel.CENTER);
        headLabel.add(browsLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

        //  Nose
        //ImageIcon nose = new ImageIcon();
        //JLabel noseLabel = new JLabel(nose, JLabel.CENTER);
        //facePanel.add(noseLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Mouth
        //ImageIcon mouth = new ImageIcon();
        //JLabel mouthLabel = new JLabel(nose, JLabel.CENTER);
        //facePanel.add(mouthLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public class Handler implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(checkBoxBrows.isSelected())
            {
                brows = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/coolBrows.png"));
                System.out.println("here"); //For testing purposes. This does come through in the console
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so you obviously know how to add components to a container, removing them is pretty much the same process, but calling `remove`. When doing this on a container which is realised on the screen, you'll need to call `revalidate` and more often than not `repaint` on the container to generate a layout and paint pass.  In your case, I'm wondering if you should just update a preexisting `JLabel` with the new image (ie `setIcon`)

Comment: Thank you for this I used setIcon() and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like you need to layer `Icons` or `JLabels`.

So maybe you can use:

1. A `JLayeredPane` to layer the labels. So you create a layer for each facial feature and add a label to the layer. Then you can add/remove the Icon from the label based on the value of the check box. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more information and working examples.
2. Use the [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) to layer the icons. This allows you to stack Icons on top of one another and then display the resulting `Icon` on a single `JLabel`. So every time an event is generated by clicking on a check box you can rebuild the `CompoundIcon` with the selected features and reset the `Icon` on the `JLabel`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I looked into JLayeredPane, it seems that that is built to do what I was attempting. I'm going to rewrite this to work with layers for practice.